# Extract different col in every row of an R data.frame

Tags: r

I have a vector of colnames that is as long as the number of rows in a data frame:

```
> x <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(3,2,1), c=c(5,6,4))
> cols <- c("c", "a", "b")
> x
  a b c
1 1 3 5
2 2 2 6
3 3 1 4
```

Now I want to extract from `x` the column `cols[i]` for each row `i` of `x`, that is 5, 2, 1 in this case. I have tried to create a matrix with T and F depending on the macth:

```
> A <- matrix(rep(colnames(x),nrow(x)), nrow=nrow(x), ncol=ncol(x), byrow=TRUE) == cols
> A
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

This looks correct, but when I use this as an index, the result is returned by row:

```
> x[A]
[1] 2 1 5
```

Does someone know of the proper way to solve this indexing problem?

Comment: what do you expect? isn't the result what your are looking for?

Comment: I think you want `x[cbind(seq_along(cols), match(cols, names(x)))]` We need the `match()` part to turn the column names into column indexes so we can subset with a matrix as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(3,2,1), c=c(5,6,4))
cols <- c("c", "a", "b")

sapply(1:length(cols),function(i){x[i,cols[i]]})
[1] 5 2 1
```